# When should I use associative entity?

Tags: erd

I am studying DBMS and I have read that associative entity is used when there is a many to many relationships but I am confused with the graph. It has many to many relationships but did not use an associative entities. Can you explain the graph? Thank you.[image]

Comment: looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366466/when-to-use-associative-entities

Comment: @ik_zelf I already saw that question but I am still confused with the usage of associative entity, particularly on the graph, 1) can the item be an associative entity so supplier, shipment, and product will have a ternary relationship, 2) why even order and product have many to many relationships but there is no associative entity? Sorry for my questions, I still don't fully understand DBMS and I hope you can explain it. Thank you